# SDL & Image quality on iOS

Tags: ios, sdl2, png

We are just finishing a mobile game for Android and iOS.

The image quality on iOS is subpar, and we are trying to understand why.

We are currently having two problems: the background, which is a gradient, is shown using few colors and the grandient's steps are very visible, and the fonts are pixelated.

I think both issues are clearly visible in this screenshot from the simulator (zoom in if needed):

[image: Screenshot of main menu of our game]

The simulator is running an iPhone Xs with Graphics Quality Override set to High Quality.

I have disabled “Compressing PNG files”, but the result is the same. This issue is not always so visible, or, at least, not on all devices. On a smaller iPhone (e.g., 7, so 4.7"), there are no noticeable issues with the image quality and the font pixelation is minimal.

We are probably going to disable support for iPad because of this.

Do you have any hints on what we can do?

Thanks!

Comment: What image format are you using when uploading these textures to the GPU?

Comment: My crystal ball says the video mode for the app ends up being 16-bits-per-pixel. Does your game use OpenGL? If it does, you can use `SDL_GL_SetAttribute` to request 24/32 bpp.

Comment: I used SDL_GL_GetAttribute to request the size of the RGBA channels (SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, etc.) and got 8, 8, 8, 0.

Comment: If I request sRGB, the alpha is 8 bits size but the background colors are weird, even though the png says it's using GIMP's sRGB Color Profile.

Comment: We never really figured it out, but ended up painting a gradient with SDL and using an image over it that is mostly transparent. It works, but it's not perfect.